# How to link a text input with associated error message in a reusable React component

Tags: reactjs, use-ref

I have a React component called `TextInput` which looks like this:

```
const TextInput = React.forwardRef<HTMLInputElement, ITextInputProps>(
  ({ error, ...props }, ref) => {
    return (
        <>
            <input
                type="text" 
                aria-describedby="" //  see here
                ref={ref}
                {...props}
            />
            {error && (
                <p> //  how can I reference this?
                    {error}
                </p>
            )}
        </>
    )}
)
```

For accessibility, I am trying to link the error message to the field using `aria-describedby`.

In a normal HTML document I would just use the `id` of the paragraph tag, but with reusability in mind, I would like to learn how to do this in a React-like way.

The use of refs comes to mind, but I'm not sure how to apply it in this scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that the best way to do this is to create a required `prop` that handles the ID and you apply that ID on the `aria` fields.

With that in mind, if what you wanted is to generate the data dinamically you could use a `useEffect` running it only once and setting a state inside it.

```
function Component() {
  const [describedBy, setDescribedBy] = useState()

  useEffect(() => {
    setDescribedBy(generateRandomString());
  }, [])

  return (
    <div aria-describedby={describedBy}></div>
  )
}
```